# Can I say "less bigger" or "more weaker" and similar phrases?

Tags: ellipsis, comparative-constructions, comparative

Suppose that

1. **A** is bigger than **B**
2. **B** is bigger than **C**

Now, is it fine if I say,

> Compared to **A**, **B** is less bigger than **C**?

If so, in this context, can I remove the first part in the almost formal settings like an academic writing?

> **B** is less bigger than **C**?

Comment: I've never heard those usages. If I wanted to say what you said in your highlighted sentence, I would say "Compared to A, B is bigger than C by a smaller amount.", or more simply, "A is bigger than B, which is bigger than C."

Comment: You could say *Compared to A, B is only slightly bigger than C.* Or any of these: *Both A and B are bigger than C. But compared to A, B is only slightly bigger.*; *While both A and B are bigger than C, the difference between A and C is much greater than the difference between B and C.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No, you may not modify a comparative adjective in this way.**

However, in mathematics, we write **C < B < A**, which could be read in a number of ways:

1. *C is smaller than B, which is smaller than A.*
2. *A is larger than B, which is larger than C.*
3. *B lies between A and C.*

Depending on the context, any of these could work.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it surely does. I was curious to know!

Comment: @Cardinal Glad to help! If this answered your question, it would be much appreciated if you would accept it :)

Comment: Yes sure, I usually accept the answer to my questions after a day or so.

Comment: No problem, but thanks anyway!